# Check if a “run-time” multidimensional array key exists

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a “run-time” multidimensional array key exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080991/check-if-a-run-time-multidimensional-array-key-exists)

Hi,

I have a multidimensional array. I need a function that checks if a specified key exists and if not set the value.

Let's take this array

```
$config['lib']['template']['engine'] = false;
```

A function should not update the value to true when i call with:

```
checkAndSetKey('lib template engine',true);
//> Checks if isset $config['lib']['template']['engine'] and if not isset $config['lib']['template']['engine'] = true;
```

Note that my array isn't only 3 dimensional. It should be able to check and set even with only 1 dimension:

```
checkAndSetKey('genericSetting',true);
//> In this considering there isn't any $c['genericSetting'] the function set the key to true;
```

At the moment I am using an awful eval code, I would like to hear suggest :)

To dynamically check if the key exists it could be used this code:

```
$array = $config;
$keys=explode(' ',$argument1);

foreach($keys as $v) { 

    if (!array_key_exists($v,$array)) {
        //> [todo!] the current key doens't exist now we should set the value
    }

    $array = &$array[$v];
}
```

Comment: can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088115/transform-flat-array-into-a-hierarchical-multi-dimensional-array It doesn't looks like good way to change settings.

Comment: That was my own question. And they aren't DUP because that question was only to see if it was isset not to set. Read better next time

Comment: i guess if jeff closes it i will say anything  xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL actually this was just one line of code added there =/
For a moment the references confused me a bit.

Here the code :

```
function _c($key,$value) {
    global $c;

    $array = &$c;
    $keys = explode(' ',$key);

    $setValue = false;
    for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++) { 
        $v = $keys[$i];

        //> If setValue is already = true we don't need to check it again
        if (!$setValue && !array_key_exists($v,$array))
            $setValue = true;

        $array = &$array[$v];
    }

    if ($setValue)
        $array = $value;
}

//> Usage _c('lib template engine',true);
```

Comment: You may want to change `foreach` loop to `for` to iterate through all given keys. Now when you call `_c('lib template engine',true);`  with emty `$c`, you will end with `$c = array('lib' => true);` and even calling it 3 times would not set desired key

Comment: yes there are some errors with an empty $c. I need to thing about a solution

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: edited the reply. Now based on the var $setValue will set within the right array

Answer (score 1):

With slight modification (passing array as reference argument) this should work:

```
function checkAndSetKey(&$arr, $keys, $value){
    $moreKeys = strpos($keys,' ');
    if($moreKeys !== FALSE){
        $currentKey = substr($keys, 0, $moreKeys);
        $keys = substr($keys, $moreKeys+1);

        if(!isset($arr[$currentKey]) || !is_array($arr[$currentKey]))
            $arr[$currentKey] = array();

        return checkAndSetKey($arr[$currentKey], $keys, $value);
    }else{
        $currentKey = $keys;
        if(!isset($arr[$currentKey]))
            $arr[$currentKey] = $value;

        return $arr[$currentKey];
    }
}
```

Comment: without those big if the code would have looked beautfiul

Comment: Code should be efficient, readable and reusable - that makes it beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

First off, its worth bearing in mind that PHP arrays are NOT multi-dimensional, they are hierarchical.

PHP already provides a method for testing if an [array key exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). Wrapping this in your own code should be trivial, particularly if the number of levels in the array is fixed:

```
function checkAndSetKey(&$arr, $path, $default)
{
   $path=explode(' ', $path);

   if (!is_array($arr[$path[0]])) { // lib
         $arr[$path[0]]=array();
   }
   if (!is_array($arr[$path[0]][$path[1]])) { // template
         $arr[$path[0]][$path[1]]=array();
   }
   if (!array_key_exists($path[2],$arr[$path[0]][$path[1]])) { // engine
         $arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]]=$default;
   }
   return $arr[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]];
}
```

With a bit of though the method above could be adapted using recursion to handle an arbitrary number of levels.

Comment: I don't find a way in your code with recursion to make it for arbitary number